# how select dropdown list value in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have two dropdown boxes. I selected item from first dropdown but could not select value from second dropdown box. I have used chrome driver.

Here is my code.

```
    public static  void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
    {
       System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\chromedriver.exe");
       WebDriver  driver =new ChromeDriver();
       driver.get("http://localhost/ProtoD/Login.aspx");
       driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.findElement(By.id("cmbBranch_Arrow")).click();
        Thread.sleep(4000);

        List<WebElement> drops=driver.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
        System.out.println(drops.size());

        for(WebElement  obj:drops){
          System.out.println(obj.getText());
          if(obj.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Head Office")) 
          {
             obj.click();
             break;
          }     
        }

       driver.findElement(By.id("cmbFinYear_Arrow")).click();
       Thread.sleep(4000);
        List<WebElement> drops1=driver.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
                 System.out.println(drops1.size());

        for(WebElement  obj1:drops1)
        {

        System.out.println(obj1.getText());
         if(obj1.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("01-Apr-2015--31-Mar-2016"))    
          {
              obj1.click();
             break;
          }
```

I am getting error as below:-

> unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (847, 271)

My HTML code:-

```
<input id="cmbFinYear_ClientState" name="cmbFinYear_ClientState" type="hidden" autocomplete="off" value="{&quot;logEntries&quot;:[],&quot;value&quot;:-2147483644,&quot;text&quot;‌​:&quot;01-Apr-2015--31-Mar-2016&quot;,&quot;enabled&quot;:true}">
```

Comment: i selected only one dropdown list but cant select another dropdown list

Comment: Try explaining exactly what you are trying to do and what the problem is

Comment: Make sure your another dropdown not hidden due to current dropdown, it should be visible.

Comment: I have 2 dropdown list i can select the only first dropdown list.and use same code for 2nd dropdown list but the code is not run.then tell me what to do for that?

Comment: Do you have an error or exception?

Comment: Please provide DOM structure.

Comment: <input id="cmbFinYear_ClientState" name="cmbFinYear_ClientState" type="hidden" autocomplete="off" value="{&quot;logEntries&quot;:[],&quot;value&quot;:-2147483644,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;01-Apr-2015--31-Mar-2016&quot;,&quot;enabled&quot;:true}">

Answer (score 0):

Where is variable "option" declares in your code? Looks like you need to change option with obj1, and better add EqualsIgnoreCase as in snippet below:

```
for(WebElement  obj1:drops1)
{    
System.out.println(obj1.getText());
       if("01-Apr-2015--31-Mar-2016".equalsIgnoreCase(obj1.getText()))
option.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code for click:

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", obj1);
```

You can try the code below:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("cmbFinYear_Arrow")).click();
Thread.sleep(4000);
List < WebElement > drops1 = driver.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
System.out.println(drops1.size());
for (WebElement obj1: drops1) {

System.out.println(obj1.getText());
if (obj1.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("01-Apr-2015--31-Mar-2016")) {
   JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", obj1);
}
```